# How to Convert flat array to Object with key within an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

how to convert this:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c']
```

to this

```
arr = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}]
```

I already tried this code

```
arr.forEach((key,name) => Object.assign(obj, { name: key }));
```

Comment: `arr.forEach( (key,name) => arr[key] = { name: name } );`

Comment: `const output = arr.map(name => ({ name }))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array.

```js
const arr = ['a','b','c'];
const result = arr.map(el => ({ name: el }));
console.log(result);
```